# How do I put a box around a column and a row in a matrix in latex?

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix in latex and I want to put a box around the first column and another box around the first row to highlight them. Additionally it should be possible to give the highlighted fields a name. 
The names should be displayed on the right side for the highlited first row and below the highlighted column.

```
\begin{align}
m =
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \dots & 3 \\
\vdots & ~ & \vdots \\
4 & \dots & 5 \\
\end{array} \right) 
\end{align}
```

Comment: Have a look at the tikzmarks package

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nicematrix` which will create the Tikz nodes for you. Then, you draw the box around the cells with the Tikz library `fit`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\[m =
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[right-margin = 4pt] 
1 & \Ldots & 3 \\
\Vdots & ~ & \Vdots \\
4 & \Ldots & 5 \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \node [draw, rounded corners, fit = (1-3) (last-3)] { } ; 
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

The option `right-margin` is used to add space before the right parenthese.

[image: Result of the above code]

In recent version of `nicematrix`, it's also possible to use the built-in command `\Block` (and you don't have to use explicitely Tikz).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[m =
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[right-margin = 5pt] 
1 & \Ldots & \Block[draw,rounded-corners]{*-1}{}3 \\
\Vdots & ~ & \Vdots \\
4 & \Ldots & 5 \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

The output is not exactly the same.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with tikz and the tikzmark library. This library allows to put specific named nodes anywhere in a page and you can add graphics illustrations with tiks at these points.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}


\begin{align}
m =
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\tikzmarknode{n1}{1} & \dots & \tikzmarknode{n3}{3} \\
\vdots & ~ & \vdots \\
\tikzmarknode{n4}{4}  & \dots & \tikzmarknode{n5}{5}  \\
\end{array} \right) 
\end{align}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,
  highlight/.style={draw=blue,rounded corners, thick, 
                    minimum width=1.5em,minimum height=2.5ex},
  note/.style={font=\small,red,text width=3cm},
  ]
  \node[highlight] at ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:n1) {};
  \node[note,left=0.5cm,anchor=east] at (pic cs:n1) 
                      {Element $(1,1)$ of matrix equals 1};
  \draw[highlight] ([yshift=2ex,xshift=1em]pic cs:n3) 
                   rectangle ([yshift=-1ex,xshift=-1em]pic cs:n5)  
                   node [note,midway,right=0.5cm] {This is last column of matrix} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`highight`is the style that draws the boxes around elements and `note` is the style used for the comments. Besides that some tweaks are required to properly position the elements.

Note that two latex run  are required to have a proper display.

[image]

EDIT:

Tikzmark is in most latex distributions like texlive, for instance. But, if for some reasons, it is not in your distribution, add the following command in your latex preamble:

```
\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[2][]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),#1] \node (#1) {#2};}
```

Then you can use `\mytikzmark` instead if `\tikzmarknode`. 
The node node name will just be the first operand of your command.

```
\mytikzmark{n1}{1} & ...
...

\node[highlight] at ([yshift=1ex]n1) {}; % instead of pic cs:n1
```

Other features of tikzmark are no longer available, but for simple mark it is sufficient. Note you may have to modify the minimal node size in the style and/or the node shift.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Unfortunately if I try to use 'tikzmark' it does not compile anymore. Is there also a way without using it?

Comment: There is simple replacement, see edit. But is still require tikz. Without tikz, you can look at the textpos package, but it is much more complex to use.